# python Cv2-Draw Contours and fill black is ignoring perimeter

Tags: python, opencv

Iam trying to remove objects from the image using the following method, however, as can be seen from outcome image there is a residual fine colored line around each object. Although i have dilated my image, the lines are still present.

Is there a way to remove those lines?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('TRY.jpg')
  
image_edges = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3,3),1) #Helps in defining the edges
image_edges=cv2.Canny(image_edges,100,200)

image_edges=cv2.dilate(image_edges,(3,3),iterations=3)


contours_draw, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image_edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

mask = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)
mask.fill(255)
for c in contours_draw:

    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), -1) 

mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


res = img.copy()
res[mask == 0] = 255


cv2.imshow('img', res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Original Image

[image]

--

Outcome Image

[image]

Comment: The reason is because of open (non-closed) contour. You can use ```for c in contours_draw:
    for i in range(len(c)-1):
        cv2.line(mask,tuple(c[i][0]),tuple(c[i+1][0]),(0,0,0),1)```

Answer (score 0):

The outlines are still there because the threshold is too high.

Try this:

```
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 20, 255, 0)
contours_draw, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

The values you pass to the threshold function determine how inclusive or exclusive the findContours function is going to be.  Put low numbers if you want a low threshold, and high numbers if you want a high one.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. When i apply the threshold it completely removed the 8 shapes. I want to still to get their contours, in case I want to inpaint them or perform any operations to those contours.

Comment: wait so you didn't want to remove the outlines of the shapes, just the color in those outlines?

Comment: I want to remove the residual outlines but i also want the contours of all shapes. When i applied the threshold, all the geometric shapes were removed (except for middle writing), so i wont be able to get the contours of the geometric shapes. Ideally, When i apply the RETR_External,all the outlines should be within the contour? Not sure why there is residual lines.